# Business Process Error when Merging Case records via C#

Tags: c#, plugins, merge, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I created a post-operation plugin on create of "incident."  The rule is to merge any "incident" created with the same title within 30 days.  I have query expressions that get me the data that I need.  If there are 0 matches with the same title the case is created, if there are more than one match, I query that title by createdon ascending to get me the very first "incident" created ID. My tracers show that all the data is correct that I'm getting. My problem is at the merge with the following code below:

```
                                //merge tickets here
                            EntityReference masterTicket = new EntityReference();
                            masterTicket.Id = (Guid)masterTicketId;
                            masterTicket.LogicalName = "incident";

                            MergeRequest merge = new MergeRequest();
                            merge.SubordinateId = targetIncidentId;
                            merge.Target = masterTicket;
                            merge.PerformParentingChecks = false;
                            tracer.Trace($"Merging {targetIncidentId} into {masterTicket.Id}.");
                            var merged = (MergeResponse)service.Execute(merge);
                            tracer.Trace($"Merged Response: {merged}");
```

I have used the following examples here: [merge link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.mergerequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9)

The issue I think might be that all code that I have seen they are updating records as well.  I don't want to update any of the records, I just want to merge the records with the matching title.

I've been fighting with this for awhile now and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:** The plugin trace log is show it's failing at:

```
var merged = (MergeResponse)service.Execute(merge);
```

Because the tracer after that line is not showing in the trace logs.

> **EDIT:**  The following is the error log file:
>
> > ```
> > Unhandled exception:  Exception type: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]
> > ```
> >
> > Message: An error occurred in the following plugin:Detail: 
> >     
> >     80609179-2920-4a9e-91b9-65b10a3a3a4c
> >     -2147220891   
> >         
> >           OperationStatus
> >           0
> >         
> >         
> >           SubErrorCode
> >           -2146233088
> >               http%3a%2f%2fgo.microsoft.com%2ffwlink%2f%3fLinkID%3d398563%26lcid%3d1033%26error%3dMicrosoft.Crm.CrmException%26client%3dplatform%26sv%3d9.0.42.1001%26de%3dLive%26opsys%3dMicrosoft+Windows+NT+10.0.14393.0%26errorCode%3d-2147220891
> >     An error occurred in the following plugin:
> >     2019-10-21T14:20:08.3608048Z
> >     false
> >
> > [ORG_Dynamics365: ORG_Dynamics365.TicketStacking]
> >     [e5b0700e-e3f0-e911-a812-000d3a33f7ca: ORG_Dynamics365.TicketStacking:
> >     Create of incident] Entered
> >     Microsoft.Dynamics.Service.Plugins.PreOperationIncidentCreate.Execute(),
> >     Correlation Id: 970488ac-6888-4eb6-9294-cdf1098e5371, Initiating User:
> >     bc80c76a-38d3-e911-a9b8-000d3a367d35 Exiting
> >     Microsoft.Dynamics.Service.Plugins.PreOperationIncidentCreate.Execute(),
> >     Correlation Id: 970488ac-6888-4eb6-9294-cdf1098e5371, Initiating User:
> >     bc80c76a-38d3-e911-a9b8-000d3a367d35 Entered
> >     Microsoft.Dynamics.Service.Plugins.PreOperationIncidentCreateEntitlement.Execute(),
> >     Correlation Id: 970488ac-6888-4eb6-9294-cdf1098e5371, Initiating User:
> >     bc80c76a-38d3-e911-a9b8-000d3a367d35 Exiting
> >     Microsoft.Dynamics.Service.Plugins.PreOperationIncidentCreateEntitlement.Execute(),
> >     Correlation Id: 970488ac-6888-4eb6-9294-cdf1098e5371, Initiating User:
> >     bc80c76a-38d3-e911-a9b8-000d3a367d35 Entered
> >     Microsoft.Dynamics.Service.Plugins.PostOperationIncidentCreateEntitlement.Execute(),
> >     Correlation Id: 970488ac-6888-4eb6-9294-cdf1098e5371, Initiating User:
> >     bc80c76a-38d3-e911-a9b8-000d3a367d35 Exiting
> >     Microsoft.Dynamics.Service.Plugins.PostOperationIncidentCreateEntitlement.Execute(),
> >     Correlation Id: 970488ac-6888-4eb6-9294-cdf1098e5371, Initiating User:
> >     bc80c76a-38d3-e911-a9b8-000d3a367d35
> >
> > target incident id: 8491c0df-0df4-e911-a813-000d3a33f11e target title:
> >     20191021 10:12a target raised on: 10/21/2019 2:20:08 PM traget local
> >     time now:  10/21/2019 2:20:08 PM Before retrieveMultiple After
> >     retrieveMultiple In foreach loop oldest incidentid:
> >     74e2f090-0df4-e911-a813-000d3a33f11e Title: 20191021 10:12a Master
> >     Ticket Guid: 74e2f090-0df4-e911-a813-000d3a33f11e oldest Raised On:
> >     10/21/2019 2:17:58 PM Total Record Count: 2 1 record(s) matching.
> >     Timespan is 0.00150799356481481 days greather than original ticket
> >     (less than 30 days). Ticket will be merged with original ticket.
> >     Merging 8491c0df-0df4-e911-a813-000d3a33f11e into
> >     74e2f090-0df4-e911-a813-000d3a33f11e.

Comment: Are those cases open? Any downloadable log file error or inner exception?

Comment: @ArunVinoth Yes, both cases are open and active. There is no inner exception but am editing the question with the error log file.

Comment: @ArunVinoth I've changed to plugin step to be asynchronous and the error went away. HOWEVER, the cases are not merged.

Comment: @ArunVinoth While it didn't through a business process error after switching it to asynch, I do still see errors in the logs.

Comment: Were you able to merge two cases manually? Looks like some internal plugin throwing exception in CreateEntitlement / TicketStacking..

Comment: @ArunVinoth yes, I was able to merge the cases manually.  One thing to note is that there are MANY third party Provance ITSM plugins firing as well, I can't help but think that might be a problem. Would you agree?  If so, how would I fix this to get my plugin to fire at thte correct time?

Comment: you can check the execution order of your plugin step & adjust it. https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/242985/how-to-set-order-of-the-plugin-to-be-fired/671081

Comment: You should also report a bug with the third party provider too

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

After the back & forth conversation in comments, concluded the below points:

1. There are some third party ITSM plugins firing on case merge and the error bubbling out
2. To control the order of plugin step execution, we have to use the `Execution order` of steps registered for sequencing firing order

[Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/242985/how-to-set-order-of-the-plugin-to-be-fired/671081)